# Re-entering copied city - how to exit?

Tags: nier-automata

Later in the game, you can reenter the copied city. I want to do this using 9S as there is a box in there only he can open.  I've gone in, but it seems like in the area where you

> fight Adam,

the machines lifeforms respawn endlessly and I can't find an exit.  How do I get out?

Comment: Okay, the fact that your entire question is spoiler text is kinda a problem. Is there any way you can ask it without needing to block it like this? You seem to spoil some of it in the title test anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exit the copied city as 9S

> or A2

you simply go back into the elevator that you entered from.

Comment: I went all around multiple times and didn't see any elevator.  I suppose I might have missed it though, I'll look again.

Comment: @Andy it's the same elevator you use to get in. The copied city only has one entrance/exit.

Comment: Ok... it blended in well and I didn't notice the green light next to it.  Thanks!